# Wordpress: How to count occurrences of strings in wp_posts db column

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'v been looking at several tutorials and stackoverflow answers, but I can't get this to work for me. Basically, I want tp echo the number of instances a certain string is mentioned through all posts.

Here's what I've cobbled together so far using answers I've read. I'm putting this inside a loop for a page template:

```
$count = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'string I want to count','')) AS 'occurs' FROM wp_db WHERE post_content LIKE '%string I want to count%'");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $count += $data['occurs'];
}
echo $count;
```

This seems to break my template though and nothing gets echoed.

Hoping someone can help me recognize what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Comment: `'occurs'` in the query should have no quotes, or you can use backticks.

Comment: Note you need to divide the returned value by `strlen('string I want to count')` to get the actual count of occurrences

Comment: @Nick where do I inject that into my code?

Comment: You can do it in the query e.g. `(LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'string I want to count',''))) / LENGTH('string I want to count') AS occurs` or in your PHP `$count += $data['occurs'] / strlen('string I want to count');`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those options worked. Still just getting a blank page.

Comment: @Nick I also took the quote marks off of the 'occurs' in the query - thanks for that. Still not working though, and I'm afraid people won't help with this question now that it's been closed. Please advise.

Comment: Just noticed you're using `mysql` functions - surely you've upgraded to `mysqli` by now?

Comment: I'm taking a stab at this, but not really fluent with sql yet. I assume I used some depreciated code. Can I just change the 2 `mysql` functions to `msqli`?

Comment: I've run this code using `mysqli` functions on my server and it runs: `$conn = mysqli_connect('test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
$conn->query('create table wp_db (post_content text)') or die($conn->error);
$conn->query("insert into wp_db values ('hello world. hello yourself!')") or die($conn->error);
$count = 0;
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT LENGTH(post_content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(post_content,'hello','')) AS occurs FROM wp_db WHERE post_content LIKE '%hello%'") or die($conn->error);
while ($data = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $count += $data['occurs'];
}
echo $count / strlen('hello');`

Comment: What does your db connection code look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206384/discussion-between-eric-brockman-and-nick).